# OpenVPN and Asterisk - Ekiga or Empathy is unable to register the service

Tags: openvpn, empathy, asterisk, ekiga

Given is the following configuration: An Openwrt router with Asterisk and OpenVPN installed, an Ubuntu 14.04 client with Ekiga and Empathy. 
I would like to connect thorough VPN to Asterisk server with Ubuntu client.
The another client running Android and SIPsimple runs via VPN fine.
Connection to the VPN service from Ubuntu client can be established and other services are running fine. The message in Ekiga and Empathy is unable to register service.

Is there any additional setup possible regarding routing between Ekiga or Empathy on the Ubuntu client?

Asterisk via VPN from the local network on the Ubuntu client works. The problem is any remote network outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Empathy client works as well with following settings:

```
sip address: username@10.0.0.1

Special settings:

proxy settings: only set port to 5060, the address leave blank
username: set your username
local address: use your tun device address from ifconfig when connected to vpn (e.g. 10.0.0.6)
checkboxes: uncheck all options
transport: choose your transport defined in Asterisk' settings
all other settings: leave default
```

The Ekiga settings are following:

```
Registrator: 10.0.0.1
user: your sip username
registered user: your sip username
password: your sip password
timeout: 3600

proxy: leave empty
forwarding URI: leave empty
```

SIP server settings:

The sip.conf for Asterisk does have to contain a line:

```
localnet=10.0.0.0/8
```

The openvpn configuration file in /etc/config has to contain:

```
option server '10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0'
```

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 Empathy 3.8.6, Ubuntu 15.10 Empathy 3.12 and Ubuntu 14.04 Ekiga 4.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to try MicroSip http://www.microsip.org/ through Wine first. Works perfect. Had a lot problems with Ekiga and Empathy.

The remote address of Asterisk service through OpenVPN has to change to 10.0.0.1 for remote networks.

The sip.conf for Asterisk does have to contain a line:

```
localnet=10.0.0.0/8
```

The openvpn configuration file in /etc/config has to contain:

```
option server '10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

The another possibility is to use [Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/), which has native linux client. The settings are the same:

The remote address of Asterisk service through OpenVPN has to change to 10.0.0.1 for remote networks.

The sip.conf for Asterisk does have to contain a line:

```
localnet=10.0.0.0/8
```

The openvpn configuration file in /etc/config has to contain:

```
option server '10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0'
```

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit with remote VPN.

Answer (score 0):

The another working client is [Jitsi](http://jitsi.org). The settings are the same as in previous answers.